# Display appointments on specified date in access

Tags: database, ms-access

thank you for all of the previous help.

I have produced a database in access (specified by course) and I was wondering if it is possible to produce a query/report that asks for the user to input a date and then display the  appointments on the specified date. e.g. 09/05/2013 (british date system) Googled for hours and not found exactly what I was looking for.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is definitely possible in Access.  You can create a Form with a search field at the top, and display the results accordingly.

A good first step would be to build a query that displays the appointments by date.  [This link](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/examples-of-query-criteria-HA010066611.aspx#BM4) has great tips on that.

Here's another link that will walk you through using the query as a source for data in the form: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/use-a-query-as-the-record-source-for-a-form-or-report-HA010096318.aspx

EDIT:  if you don't require a pretty form, you can skip that part.  The query can be written so it [asks the user to input the date criteria](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/watch-this-make-a-query-ask-for-input-HA010256398.aspx)